# CeleryExecutor: Does the airflow metric "executor.queued_tasks" report the number of tasks in the celery broker?

Tags: celery, airflow

Using its [statsd plugin](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/metrics.html), Airflow can report on metric `executor.queued_tasks` as well as some others.

I am using CeleryExecutor and need to know how many tasks are waiting in the Celery broker, so I know when new workers should be spawned. Indeed, I set my workers so they cannot take many tasks concurrently. Is this metric what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. If you want to know how many TIs are waiting in the broker, you'll have to connect to it.

Task instances that are waiting to get picked up in the celery broker are queued according to the Airflow DB, but running according to the CeleryExecutor. This is because the CeleryExecutor considers that any task instance that was successfully sent to the broker is now running (unlike the DB, which waits for a worker to pick it up before marking it as running).

Metric `executor.queued_tasks` reports the number of tasks queued according to the executor, not the DB.

The number of queued task instances according to the DB is not exactly what you need either, because it reports the number of task instances that are waiting in the broker *plus* the number of task instances queued to the executor. But when would TIs be stuck in the executor's queue, you ask? When the `parallelism` setting of Airflow prevents the executor from sending them to the broker.